# Using Renderscript for game development on android

Tags: android

Does any one know anything about using Renderscript for game development in Android 3.0. If you know, can you provide some good examples or demo links?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Renderscript for gamedev. It doesn't use GPU today and it is not portable.
libgdx author has tried Renderscript and there is an [interesting debate](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=1561).

Answer (score -2):

render script may is depreciated as a graphics library, but it may still be useful if you are using it to calculate physics or other parallelized tasks.

Comment: Hi, could you make your answer a bit more clear?